# Hibernate OneToMany List or Iterator different?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-onetomany

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {

    private long studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private List<Phone> studentPhoneNumbers;

    ....

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_PHONE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PHONE_ID") })
    public List<Phone> getStudentPhoneNumbers() {
        return this.studentPhoneNumbers;
    }

    public void setStudentPhoneNumbers(List<Phone> studentPhoneNumbers) {
        this.studentPhoneNumbers = studentPhoneNumbers;
    }
}
```

1)

```
Student student = session.loadStudent(123); // pseudocode
List phoneList = student.getStudentPhoneNumbers();
for (Phone p : phoneList) {
    ...
}
```

2)

```
Student student = session.loadStudent(123); // pseudocode
List phoneList = student.getStudentPhoneNumbers();
Iterator itr = phoneList.iterator();   
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    ...
}
```

I read the answer from here: [difference between query.list and query.iterate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957220/difference-between-query-list-and-query-iterate)

Obviously there is difference between `list()` and `iterator()` (in `Query`). What if I use it in the `OneToMany` list? like the example above, is there difference in term of performance? memory?

Comment: @Scary Wombat, how this question duplicate with that one? Hibernate implicitly create proxy wrap up the `List` object, calling these two method may have different impact.

Comment: The two snippets of code you posted do exactly the same thing. The foreach loop of the first snippet uses List.iterator() behind the scene, just like you're doing in the second snippet. That has nothing to do with Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read up this [Hibernate chapter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html) which explain the proxy performance in detail.

The entity's mapping `FetchType` by default is `lazy`, which, hibernate will create a proxy around the attribute.

Upon calling `list.size()` (and etc), hibernate will start to load all the children objects.

If we don't want to load all, we can use the new feature called `extra lazy`. It will issue `select` statement for specific record only, for example, `list.get(3)` select fourth row only.

If we annotate the attribute with `eager`, then hibernate will load all the children objects (use outer join, which will have duplicate issue) upon it load the parent object. In this case, there is no proxy wrapping around the attribute. It will not have performance difference, not matter we use it as a `list` or `iterator`.

Comment: What you write about lazy-fetching proxy is correct. However it does ***NOT*** apply to your original question.  In your question, you are asking to use for-each loop and iterator to iterate through a collection.  There is nothing lazy-fetching proxy is making a difference here.

Comment: Ya, it was my mistake, I was not aware of for-each and iterator are the same thing and my example code are a bit confusing, in fact, I was looking for how to retrieve the item one by one or the whole list, and compare the performance. I will edit my question if there is time. thanks reminder.

Comment: What you said is still wrong. Your answer has nothing to do with "one-by-one" vs "whole list". Lazy collection proxy is going to fetch the whole list when accessed

Comment: That's why I found the solution `Extra-lazy` will load the record one-by-one.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with Hibernate.

When Java Compiler encounters

```
for (Phone p : phoneList) {
    ....
}
```

it automatically generate code equivalent to

```
for (Iterator<Phone> itr = phoneList.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
    Phone p = itr.next();
    ....
}
```

So it is essentially the same for that two examples you are showing.